# tails of a log-concave density are sub-exponential.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

**Definition 1:** A density $g$ is called log-concave on $(a,b)\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ if there exists a concave function $\varphi(x)$ such that

$$g(x)=e^{\varphi(x)}.$$

**Definition 2:** a random variable $X$ with mean $\mu$ is sub-exponential if there are non-negative parameters $(\nu,\lambda)$ such that

$$\mathbb{E}[e^{t(X-\mu)}]\le e^{t^2\nu^2/2}\;\;\forall |t|<1/\lambda.$$

**Question:** if $X$ is distributed over $(a,b)$ according to some distribution $G$ with log-concave density $g$, is $X$ necessarily sub-exponential? Is this equivalent to saying that tails of $g$ are sub-exponential?

I found an article claiming that tails of a log-concave density are necessarily sub-exponential, but I cannot see why.